# Jobrunr with non-spring-based java web application

Tags: java, jobrunr

How can the jobrunr be integrated with non-spring-based java applications? I am trying to integrate jobrunr 4.0.6 with non-spring-based Java application but facing issues in getting the dashboard and the background server working.

Any help / direction regarding this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public JobRunrConfiguration.JobRunrConfigurationResult initJobRunr() {
InMemoryStorageProvider storageProvider = new InMemoryStorageProvider();
(new InMemoryStorageProvider()).setJobMapper(new JobMapper(new JacksonJsonMapper()));
return JobRunr.configure()
        .useStorageProvider(storageProvider)
        .useBackgroundJobServer()
        .useDashboard()
        .initialize();
```

}

Error: No classDef found error for obrunr/core/src/main/java/org/jobrunr/dashboard/server/HttpExchangeHandler

Comment: It appears you do not have the complete JobRunr jar in your classpath. Did you alter or change this JobRunr jar?

Comment: Nope, I use maven and I have mentioned the Jackson Bind and Jobrunr in the pom.xml. Included the above code to be called on the server startup.

Answer (score 2):

Below workaround made it work for me,

add the below snippet in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
        <system>
            <paths>
                <path name="com/sun/net/httpserver"/>
            </paths>
        </system>
```

To the server startup add,

```
    public JobRunrConfiguration.JobRunrConfigurationResult initJobRunr() {
    InMemoryStorageProvider storageProvider = new InMemoryStorageProvider();
    (new InMemoryStorageProvider()).setJobMapper(new JobMapper(new JacksonJsonMapper()));
    return JobRunr.configure()
            .useStorageProvider(storageProvider)
            .useBackgroundJobServer()
            .useDashboard(5000)// if you want to customize the port
            .useJmxExtensions()
            .initialize();
}
```